Regex Remove spaces in front of punctuation
Hi I'm trying to replace spaces in front of punctuation using regex.  I want to use Replace in c# - trying to replace with Regex a call like this:
value = value
  .Replace(" !", "!")
  .Replace(" .", ".")
  .Replace(" ,", ",")
  .Replace(" ?", "?")
  .Replace(" ;", ";")
  .Replace(" :", ":");


You can try using regular expression like this:
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;

...

value = Regex.Replace(value, @"\s+(?=\p{P})", "");

Pattern \s+(?=\p{P}) explained:
  \s+       - one or more whitespaces
  (?=\p{P}) - any punctuation - \p{P} - not included to the match (?=)

if you want to remove only regular, not white spaces, use @" +(?=\p{P})" pattern.
If you want not all but only some punctuation, say !?.,;:, you should put it into pattern like this: @"\s+(?=[!?.,;:])"
